# Modaless / non-modal window for Angular 2 / 4

Tags: angular

Does anyone know any tool for creating a **modaless** / non-modal window in Angular 4?

I used to use [ngPopup](http://markocen.github.io/ngPopup/ngPopupDemo.html) for my angularJS project but there seems no updated version for angular 4.

So I'm looking for something similar, can anyone give some suggestion?

**Note: It has to be MODALESS instead of a modal window**

Comment: You can have a look at [Angular2 UI](https://ng2-ui.github.io/dist/#/popup). It  provides `modals` and much more.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [Angular2 UI](https://ng2-ui.github.io/dist/#/popup). It  provides `modals` and much more.

---

Here's the HTML Template part:

```
<ngui-popup #popup></ngui-popup>
<br/>
  {{message}}
<br/>

<button (click)="openPopup('small', 'Hello Small Popup')">open small message popup</button>
<br/>

 <button (click)="openPopup('medium', 'Hello Medium Popup')">open medium message popup</button>
<br/>
```

---

Here's the Component part:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import { NguiPopupComponent, NguiMessagePopupComponent } from 'ngui-ui';

  export class popupComponent {
    @ViewChild(NguiPopupComponent) popup: NguiPopupComponent;
    message: string;

    openPopup(size, title) {
      this.popup.open(NguiMessagePopupComponent, {
        classNames: size,
        title: title,
        message: "This is message given using popup.open()",
        buttons: {
          OK: () => {
            this.message = "Ok button is pressed";
          },
          CANCEL: () => {
            this.message = "Cancel button is pressed";
            this.popup.close();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Manubhargav but I don't want **modal** window, I need to also edit something else on the page when the window is open.